# Threads sharing instance variables

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I want both threads to share the variable, but sometimes at run time it prints out 2 twice, instead of 1 and 2.

```
public class man implements Runnable{

    int value = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Runnable job = new man();
        Thread work1 = new Thread(job);
        work1.setName("Thread1");
        Thread work2 = new Thread(job);
        work2.setName("Thread2");

        work1.start();
        work2.start();
    }


    public void run(){
        synchronized(this){
            value = value + 1;
        }
        System.out.println("VALUE = " + value +", Running " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }



}
```

The output sometimes is:

```
VALUE = 2, Running Thread2
VALUE = 2, Running Thread1
```

and other times is:

```
VALUE = 1, Running Thread2
VALUE = 2, Running Thread1
```

Why is this happening? I am learning Java in a HeadFirst book and this question came up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not synchronizing the access within the `System.out.println` call, so occasionally the "second" thread increments before the "first thread" prints.

Answer (score 3):

You need to synchronize access to the variable.

What is happening is that both threads are reading the value of the variable after both have incremented it.  In other words:

1. Thread 1:  syncronized(this) => Thread 2 can't enter into its own syncronized(this)
2. Thread 1:  value= value + 1 ; => say 1
3. Thread 1:  Ends syncronized block => Thread 2 can enter into its own syncronized(this) now
4. Thread 2:  syncronized(this) => Thread 1 can't enter into its own syncronized(this)
5. Thread 2:  value= value + 1 ; => 2
6. Thread 2:  prints value, i.e. 2
7. Thread 1:  prints value, i.e. 2

The solution is to move `System.out.println("VALUE = " + value +", ...);` inside the `synchronized` block.  This forces reordering of the sequence above into:

1. Thread 1:  syncronized(this) => Thread 2 can't enter into its own syncronized(this)
2. Thread 1:  value= value + 1 ; => say 1
3. Thread 1:  prints value, i.e. 1
4. Thread 1:  Ends syncronized block => Thread 2 can enter into its own syncronized(this) now
5. Thread 2:  syncronized(this) => Thread 1 can't enter into its own syncronized(this)
6. Thread 2:  value= value + 1 ; => 2
7. Thread 2:  prints value, i.e. 2